# Series Summation in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I have a 1D matrix (A) of 5 000 000 elements and I would like to do a series summation of these data so that the result (matrix "B") is also a 5 000 000 element long 1D matrix, where each element B[i] is the sum of element A[i] and all elements before A[i].

The code below is what I have so far. That code does not quite cut it as the run time for doing each summation in the series decreases with the number of summations (index value) until the process finally terminates itself before it is done (i.e., before reaching the 5 millionth index).

Is there a more efficient way of summarizing such long series? Is there perhaps a python function to do this?

```
import numpy as np
# Create the fake data:
A = np.arange(5000000)
B = np.zeros([5000000])
for i in np.arange(5000000):
    B[i] = np.sum(A[0:i])
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are describing is known as cumulative summation, for which NumPy has a builtin function:

```
B = np.cumsum(A)
```

If you want to write it yourself, you should make use of the property `B[i] = B[i-1] + A[i]`. That is, the `i`'th sum is the same as the `(i-1)`'th sum plus the `i`'th value of `A`:

```
B = np.zeros(5000000)
for i in xrange(1, 5000000):
    B[i] = B[i-1] + A[i]
```

This has O(n) complexity, as opposed to O(n²) for the algorithm in your question. Note also that I've used `xrange` and not `np.arange`. This is better when doing loops, as `xrange` produce one integer at a time, meaning that it consumes less memory than `np.arange`.

Comment: Splendid! This was just the kind of function that I was looking for! Thank you also for the more pedagogically written code in your second answer!

Comment: Is there also a version of np.cumsum() that deals with NaN values (similar to np.nansum() )? (Because I have some NaNs in A) 
I tried with np.nancumsum() but I got the error message that:
" 'module' object has no attribute 'nancumsum' "
Or is it just easier to set my NaN values to zero before summing with np.cumsum() ?

Comment: Not directly, I think. If you just want to skip the `NaN`s, you can just remove them before doing the summation: `np.cumsum(A[~np.isnan(A)])`. Here, `np.isnan(A)` is a boolean mask telling where the elements in `A` *are* `NaN`. This is then flipped to telling where the elements *are not* `NaN` using `~`. Using this as an index to `A` itself now picks out only those elements which are not `NaN`.

Answer (score 3):

You could take advantage of the fact that `B[i-1]` is the sum of all the numbers before it. This means that the next element (`B[i]`) is just `B[i-1]+A[i]`. This would save iterating though `A[0]` to `A[i]` during iteration.

Here is a function that would do this:

```
def sumMatrix(A):
    #Define the return array, B, populated with 0
    B = [0]
    #Iterate through the provided array, A
    for number in A:
        #Set the next element to the sum of the last element in B
        #  and the next number in A
        B.append(B[-1] + number)
    #Return B, removing the 0 in the first element
    return B[1:]

#Call the function with the numbers from 1 to 5,000,000 and output
#  the result
print(sumMatrix(range(5000000)))
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you! You guys really spoil me (and other python beginners) with solutions today!